# Set WPF MenuItem Icon in Style from attached property

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, data-binding, wpf-style

I'm trying to move some XAML defining **MenuItem** into a **Style**.

I've got the following working XAML:

```
<Menu x:Name="menu" Height="19" Margin="10,10,10.333,0" VerticalAlignment="Top">
        <MenuItem Header="_Open">
            <MenuItem.Icon>
                <Viewbox>
                    <ContentControl Content="{DynamicResource appbar.folder.open}" RenderTransformOrigin="0.5,0.5">
                        <ContentControl.RenderTransform>
                            <TransformGroup>
                                <ScaleTransform ScaleX="2" ScaleY="2"/>
                            </TransformGroup>
                        </ContentControl.RenderTransform>
                    </ContentControl>
                </Viewbox>
            </MenuItem.Icon>
        </MenuItem>
</Menu>
```

where the resource looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ResourceDictionary xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation" xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml">
    <Canvas xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation" xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml" 
            x:Key="appbar.folder.open" Width="76" Height="76" Clip="F1 M 0,0L 76,0L 76,76L 0,76L 0,0">
        <Path Width="44" Height="26" Canvas.Left="19" Canvas.Top="24" Stretch="Fill" Fill="#FF000000" Data="F1 M 19,50L 28,34L 63,34L 54,50L 19,50 Z M 19,28.0001L 35,28C 36,25 37.4999,24.0001 37.4999,24.0001L 48.75,24C 49.3023,24 50,24.6977 50,25.25L 50,28L 53.9999,28.0001L 53.9999,32L 27,32L 19,46.4L 19,28.0001 Z "/>
    </Canvas>
</ResourceDictionary>
```

As a sidenote, i also don't know how to get rid of the explicit scaling. It seems to be a minor problem but i would appreciate if this could be solved as well.

Anyway, to move as much as possible of this somewhat too expressive definition into a Style, I created code for an attached property of type Visual

```
namespace extensions
{
    public class AttachedProperties
    {
        public static readonly DependencyProperty VisualIconProperty =
            DependencyProperty.RegisterAttached("VisualIcon",
                typeof(System.Windows.Media.Visual), typeof(AttachedProperties),
                new PropertyMetadata(default(System.Windows.Media.Visual)));

        public static void SetVisualIcon(UIElement element, System.Windows.Media.Visual value)
        {
            element.SetValue(VisualIconProperty, value);
        }
        public static System.Windows.Media.Visual GetVisualIcon(UIElement element)
        {
            return (System.Windows.Media.Visual)element.GetValue(VisualIconProperty);
        }
    }
}
```

redefined the menu item

```
<MenuItem Header="_Open"
          Style="{StaticResource MenuItemStyle}"
          extensions:AttachedProperties.VisualIcon="{DynamicResource appbar.folder.open}" />
```

and tried to create a Style which reads the VisualIcon property to set the Icon content

```
<Style x:Key="MenuItemStyle" TargetType="MenuItem">
    <Setter Property="MenuItem.Icon">
        <Setter.Value>
            <Viewbox>
                <ContentControl RenderTransformOrigin="0.5,0.5">
                    <ContentControl.Content>
                        <!-- this would work but doesn't reference the VisualIcon property.. <DynamicResource ResourceKey="appbar.folder.open"/> -->
                        <!-- these do not -->
                        <Binding Path="(extensions:AttachedProperties.VisualIcon)" RelativeSource="{RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType=MenuItem}"/>-->
                        <!--<Binding Path="(extensions:AttachedProperties.VisualIcon)" RelativeSource="{RelativeSource TemplatedParent}"/>-->
                        <!--<Binding Path="(extensions:AttachedProperties.VisualIcon)" RelativeSource="{RelativeSource Self}"/>-->
                    </ContentControl.Content>
                    <ContentControl.RenderTransform>
                        <TransformGroup>
                            <ScaleTransform ScaleX="2" ScaleY="2"/>
                        </TransformGroup>
                    </ContentControl.RenderTransform>
                </ContentControl>
            </Viewbox>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
```

but failed. Referencing the resource with a DynamicResource and a static key works, but i cannot get any binding using the attached property to work.

Since I'm a WPF beginner, I'm not sure if this is a good approach anyway.

**[EDIT1]**

I tested all the provided solutions.
[Grek40](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5265292/grek40)'s [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45513566/set-wpf-menuitem-icon-in-style-from-attached-property/45542753#45542753) didn't display any icons for me, neither in design view nor during runtime; maybe I did something completely wrong.

The second approach in [grx70](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2018357/grx70)'s [second answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45513566/set-wpf-menuitem-icon-in-style-from-attached-property/45541561#45541561) it the most promising for me as it reliably displays the icon in the design view as well as during runtime.
However, it seems like there's a difference between Win7 and Win10 i don't understand. I tested the identical source (on a external drive) on Win7 and Win10. For Win10, it looks nice, but Win7 draws the icons way too big.

(Note: The reason is give in [this comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45513566/set-wpf-menuitem-icon-in-style-from-attached-property?noredirect=1#comment78109196_45513566))

[image: Difference Win7/Win10]

Here's the window testcode:

```
<Window.Resources>
    <Style x:Key="MenuItemStyle" TargetType="controls:MenuItemEx">
        <Setter Property="MenuItem.Icon">
            <Setter.Value>
                <Viewbox>
                    <ContentControl RenderTransformOrigin="0.5,0.5">
                        <ContentControl.Content>
                            <Binding Path="(extensions:AttachedProperties.VisualIcon)" RelativeSource="{RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType=MenuItem}"/>
                        </ContentControl.Content>
                        <ContentControl.RenderTransform>
                            <TransformGroup>
                                <ScaleTransform ScaleX="2" ScaleY="2"/>
                            </TransformGroup>
                        </ContentControl.RenderTransform>
                    </ContentControl>
                </Viewbox>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
    </Style>
    <Style x:Key="MenuItemStyle2" TargetType="MenuItem">
        <Setter Property="uihelpers:MenuItemHelper.IsEnabled" Value="True" />
        <Setter Property="MenuItem.Icon">
            <Setter.Value>
                <Viewbox>
                    <ContentControl RenderTransformOrigin="0.5,0.5"
                        Content="{Binding
                        Path=(uihelpers:MenuItemHelper.MenuItem).(extensions:AttachedProperties.VisualIcon),
                        RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=Viewbox}}">
                        <ContentControl.RenderTransform>
                            <TransformGroup>
                                <ScaleTransform ScaleX="2" ScaleY="2"/>
                            </TransformGroup>
                        </ContentControl.RenderTransform>
                    </ContentControl>
                </Viewbox>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
    </Style>

    <Style x:Key="MenuItemStyle3" TargetType="{x:Type MenuItem}">
        <Style.Resources>
            <DataTemplate x:Key="MenuItemStyle3dt" DataType="{x:Type Style}">
                <Path Style="{Binding}"
                      Stretch="Uniform"
                      HorizontalAlignment="Center"
                      VerticalAlignment="Center" />
            </DataTemplate>
        </Style.Resources>
    </Style>
    <Style x:Key="appbar.folder.open.style3.local" TargetType="{x:Type Path}">
        <Setter Property="Fill" Value="Black" />
        <Setter Property="Data" Value="M0,26 L9,10 L44,10 L35,26 Z M0,4 L16,4 C17,1 18.5,0 18.5,0 L29.75,0 C30.3,0 31,0.7 31,1.25 L31,4 L34,4 L34,8 L8,8 L0,22.4 Z" />
    </Style>
    <extensions:PathStyle x:Key="appbar.folder.open.style3b">
        <Setter Property="Path.HorizontalAlignment" Value="Center" />
        <Setter Property="Path.VerticalAlignment" Value="Center" />
        <Setter Property="Path.Stretch" Value="Uniform" />
        <Setter Property="Path.Fill" Value="Black" />
        <Setter Property="Path.Data" Value="M0,26 L9,10 L44,10 L35,26 Z M0,4 L16,4 C17,1 18.5,0 18.5,0 L29.75,0 C30.3,0 31,0.7 31,1.25 L31,4 L34,4 L34,8 L8,8 L0,22.4 Z" />
    </extensions:PathStyle>
    <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type extensions:PathStyle}">
        <Path Style="{Binding}" />
    </DataTemplate>

    <Canvas x:Key="appbar.folder.open.style4.local" x:Shared="False" Width="76" Height="76" Clip="F1 M 0,0L 76,0L 76,76L 0,76L 0,0">
        <Path Width="44" Height="26" Canvas.Left="19" Canvas.Top="24" Stretch="Fill" Fill="#FF000000" Data="F1 M 19,50L 28,34L 63,34L 54,50L 19,50 Z M 19,28.0001L 35,28C 36,25 37.4999,24.0001 37.4999,24.0001L 48.75,24C 49.3023,24 50,24.6977 50,25.25L 50,28L 53.9999,28.0001L 53.9999,32L 27,32L 19,46.4L 19,28.0001 Z "/>
    </Canvas>
    <Viewbox x:Key="MenuItemStyle4.Icon" x:Shared="False">
        <ContentControl Content="{Binding Path=Tag,RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=MenuItem}}" RenderTransformOrigin="0.5,0.5">
            <ContentControl.RenderTransform>
                <TransformGroup>
                    <ScaleTransform ScaleX="2" ScaleY="2"/>
                </TransformGroup>
            </ContentControl.RenderTransform>
        </ContentControl>
    </Viewbox>
    <Style x:Key="MenuItemStyle4" TargetType="MenuItem">
        <Setter Property="Icon" Value="{StaticResource MenuItemStyle4.Icon}"/>
    </Style>
</Window.Resources>
<Grid>
    <Menu x:Name="menu" Height="19" Margin="10,10,10.333,0" VerticalAlignment="Top">
        <MenuItem Header="_File">
            <controls:MenuItemEx Header="_Open"
                      Style="{StaticResource MenuItemStyle}"
                      extensions:AttachedProperties.VisualIcon="{DynamicResource appbar.folder.open}" />
            <MenuItem Header="_Open"
                      Style="{StaticResource MenuItemStyle2}"
                      extensions:AttachedProperties.VisualIcon="{DynamicResource appbar.folder.open}" />
            <MenuItem Header="_Open"
                      Style="{StaticResource MenuItemStyle3}"
                      Icon="{DynamicResource appbar.folder.open.style3}" />
            <MenuItem Header="_Open"
                      Style="{StaticResource MenuItemStyle3}"
                      Icon="{DynamicResource appbar.folder.open.style3.local}" />
            <MenuItem Header="_Open" Icon="{DynamicResource appbar.folder.open.style3b}" />
            <MenuItem Header="_Open"
                      Style="{StaticResource MenuItemStyle4}"
                      Tag="{DynamicResource appbar.folder.open}" />
            <MenuItem Header="_Open"
                      Style="{StaticResource MenuItemStyle4}"
                      Tag="{DynamicResource appbar.folder.open.style4.local}" />
            <MenuItem Header="_Save">
                <MenuItem.Icon>
                    <Viewbox>
                        <ContentControl Content="{DynamicResource appbar.save}" RenderTransformOrigin="0.5,0.5">
                            <ContentControl.RenderTransform>
                                <TransformGroup>
                                    <ScaleTransform ScaleX="2" ScaleY="2"/>
                                </TransformGroup>
                            </ContentControl.RenderTransform>
                        </ContentControl>
                    </Viewbox>
                </MenuItem.Icon>
            </MenuItem>
        </MenuItem>
    </Menu>
    <Menu x:Name="menu2" Height="19" Margin="9,32,11.333,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" ItemContainerStyle="{StaticResource MenuItemStyle4}">
        <MenuItem Header="_File">
            <MenuItem Header="_Open"
                       Tag="{DynamicResource appbar.folder.open.style4.local}" />
            <MenuItem Header="_Open"
                       Tag="{DynamicResource appbar.folder.open}" />
        </MenuItem>
    </Menu>
</Grid>
```

and here are the global resources:

```
<ResourceDictionary xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation" xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml">
    <Canvas xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation" xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml" 
            x:Key="appbar.folder.open" x:Shared="False" Width="76" Height="76" Clip="F1 M 0,0L 76,0L 76,76L 0,76L 0,0">
        <Path Width="44" Height="26" Canvas.Left="19" Canvas.Top="24" Stretch="Fill" Fill="#FF000000" Data="F1 M 19,50L 28,34L 63,34L 54,50L 19,50 Z M 19,28.0001L 35,28C 36,25 37.4999,24.0001 37.4999,24.0001L 48.75,24C 49.3023,24 50,24.6977 50,25.25L 50,28L 53.9999,28.0001L 53.9999,32L 27,32L 19,46.4L 19,28.0001 Z "/>
    </Canvas>
    <Style x:Key="appbar.folder.open.style3" TargetType="{x:Type Path}">
        <Setter Property="Fill" Value="Black" />
        <Setter Property="Data" Value="M0,26 L9,10 L44,10 L35,26 Z M0,4 L16,4 C17,1 18.5,0 18.5,0 L29.75,0 C30.3,0 31,0.7 31,1.25 L31,4 L34,4 L34,8 L8,8 L0,22.4 Z" />
    </Style>
</ResourceDictionary>
```

and

```
<ResourceDictionary xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation" xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml">
    <Canvas xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation" xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml" 
            x:Key="appbar.save" Width="76" Height="76" Clip="F1 M 0,0L 76,0L 76,76L 0,76L 0,0">
        <Path Width="34.8333" Height="34.8333" Canvas.Left="20.5833" Canvas.Top="20.5833" Stretch="Fill" Fill="#FF000000" Data="F1 M 20.5833,20.5833L 55.4167,20.5833L 55.4167,55.4167L 45.9167,55.4167L 45.9167,44.3333L 30.0833,44.3333L 30.0833,55.4167L 20.5833,55.4167L 20.5833,20.5833 Z M 33.25,55.4167L 33.25,50.6667L 39.5833,50.6667L 39.5833,55.4167L 33.25,55.4167 Z M 26.9167,23.75L 26.9167,33.25L 49.0833,33.25L 49.0833,23.75L 26.9167,23.75 Z "/>
    </Canvas>
</ResourceDictionary>
```

which are merged in app.xaml:

```
<Application.Resources>
    <ResourceDictionary >
        <ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
            <ResourceDictionary Source="icons/appbar.folder.open.xaml"/>
            <ResourceDictionary Source="icons/appbar.save.xaml"/>
        </ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
    </ResourceDictionary>
</Application.Resources>
```

The reason the icons are offset is that i took them more or less 1:1 from [github.com/Templarian/WindowsIcons](https://github.com/Templarian/WindowsIcons) and was hoping that because they're provided in this format (i also tried to save them as brushes, first with Inkscape and then with Expression Design) it would be common to use them like this.

Comment: Are you getting any binding-related errors in the output window?

Comment: @Grx70 for the three different approaches, only FindAncestor logs: System.Windows.Data Error: 4 : Cannot find source for binding with reference 'RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType='System.Windows.Controls.MenuItem', AncestorLevel='1''. BindingExpression:Path=(0); DataItem=null; target element is 'ContentControl' (Name=''); target property is 'Content' (type 'Object'). Strangely, the "Self" approach shows "(0)" as the icon in the design view but not during runtime.

Comment: According to [this QA](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15725729/wpf-menuitem-icon-dimensions) `MenuItem` height differs depending on used theme. Unfortunately, there's no universal way of determining "optimal" icon size - e.g. in _Aero_ theme (the default for _Windows 7_) there are no limitations at all (there's always infinite space available during the measure pass of the layout - that stems form the `MenuItem` temlpate), hence your results (icons are getting "as big as they want"). There might be some workarounds to get things more-less working, but that begs for a different question.

Comment: @Grx70 many thanks! Really appreciate your help. I think the best and most versatile solution is the one with the derived PathStyle and the implicit DataTemplate and i will accept that answer. Btw, how did you translate the Path? Is there a tool which can do this in batch mode?

Comment: I did it manually (because it took me like 2 mins), but you could easily write such a tool in half an hour, so depending on the complexity of your project it may or may not be worth it. BTW, in the light of that you've got the icons from [this link](https://github.com/Templarian/WindowsIcons), it is understandable why the icons are so "overly complicated". As I take it, they were designed in _MS Expression Design_ (judging by the .design extension), which generates _XAML_ code representing an image, which explains the unnecessary complexity of the code itself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since it somewhat looks like an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem), I'll give you alternative approach to accomplishing your goal.

First of all, your `appbar.folder.open` resource is overly complicated. The `Canvas` is completely redundant (you can offset your `Path` by setting its `Margin`). The figures are offset within the `Path` by `19,24`, which combined with the `Path` being offset in `Canvas` leads to the necessity of using `Viewbox` together with `ScaleTransform`. Moreover, your resource is not reusable, since it can only be loaded into the visual tree once, so it would only be visible in the last place it was referenced (it would be unloaded in all the previous places). My advice would be to create a `Style` for a `Path` instead - not only is it reusable, but also extensible in the sense that you can modify other properties on the target `Path` after applying the style. Here's a minimal style to do the job (I've translated your data so that it is no longer offset):

```
<Style x:Key="appbar.folder.open" TargetType="{x:Type Path}">
    <Setter Property="Fill" Value="Black" />
    <Setter Property="Data" Value="M0,26 L9,10 L44,10 L35,26 Z M0,4 L16,4 C17,1 18.5,0 18.5,0 L29.75,0 C30.3,0 31,0.7 31,1.25 L31,4 L34,4 L34,8 L8,8 L0,22.4 Z" />
</Style>
```

Secondly, I don't quite understand the purpose of your `AttachedProperties.VisualIcon` attached property. In my approach it is completely redundant. Also, I believe that this is the part that makes the designer not display your icon properly with project code disabled. The only problem is that if we set `MenuItem.Icon="{DynamicResource appbar.folder.open}"` we'll get `System.Windows.Style` text displayed instead of the icon. And `DynamicResourceExtension` does not support converting the referenced resource out-of-the-box. But, there's a clever trick we can use to make things work - simply provide an implicit `DataTemplate` with `DataType="{x:Type Style}"` which will be automatically applied:

```
<Style x:Key="MenuItemStyle" TargetType="{x:Type MenuItem}">
    <Style.Resources>
        <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type Style}">
            <Path Style="{Binding}"
                  Stretch="Uniform"
                  HorizontalAlignment="Center"
                  VerticalAlignment="Center" />
        </DataTemplate>
    </Style.Resources>
</Style>
```

We set some additional properties on the `Path` so that it fits well into the icon area.

All we need to do now is to reference the style and the icon to have it displayed on a `MenuItem`:

```
<Menu (...)>
    <MenuItem Header="_Open"
              Style="{StaticResource MenuItemStyle}"
              Icon="{DynamicResource appbar.folder.open}" />
</Menu>
```

This approach has the additional advantage of that it works in the designer even with project code disabled (at least it does for me).

## Edit

If you want to completely separate and automate things, you could subclass `Style`:

```
public class PathStyle : Style
{
    public PathStyle()
    {
        TargetType = typeof(Path);
    }
}
```

And provide implicit `DataTemplate` in your resources dictionary:

```
<local:PathStyle x:Key="appbar.folder.open">
    <Setter Property="Path.HorizontalAlignment" Value="Center" />
    <Setter Property="Path.VerticalAlignment" Value="Center" />
    <Setter Property="Path.Stretch" Value="Uniform" />
    <Setter Property="Path.Fill" Value="Black" />
    <Setter Property="Path.Data" Value="M0,26 L9,10 L44,10 L35,26 Z M0,4 L16,4 C17,1 18.5,0 18.5,0 L29.75,0 C30.3,0 31,0.7 31,1.25 L31,4 L34,4 L34,8 L8,8 L0,22.4 Z" />
</local:PathStyle>
<DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type local:PathStyle}">
    <Path Style="{Binding}" />
</DataTemplate>
```

I moved all the properties from the `DataTemplate` to the `Style` so that it can be overridden in other styles. Note though that you need to fully qualify property names, i.e. use `Path.Data` instead of simply `Data`.

Now all you need to is to reference the resource in your view:

```
<MenuItem Icon="{DynamicResource appbar.folder.open}" (...) />
```

Or even:

```
<ContentPresenter Content="{DynamicResource appbar.folder.open}" />
```

And all the magic is done by the framework. The beauty of this approach is that you can replace your `ResourceDictionary` with one containing for example:

```
<Border x:Key="appbar.folder.open" x:Shared="False" Background="Red" />
```

And everything still works without the need to modify the views.

Comment: I've never seen `<DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type Style}">` before... do you have any source that explains this approach (with any justified usage scenario)? It looks **really** strange to me...

Comment: @grek40 I know it looks a little bit odd, and I've never seen it before either. As for explanation - we have a `Style` for a `Path` that, when applied, creates an icon, and we want to set it to `MenuItem.Icon`. Since `DynamicResourceExtension` does not support conversion, and `MenuItem` does not contain `IconTemplate` nor `IconTemplateSelector` properties, we need to fallback to using implicit `DataTemplate` to "convert" the `Style` into a `Path`. That's pretty much standard approach. Do you think there are some risks with data type being `Style` instead of some arbitrary `FooViewModel`?

Comment: edited the question as there was too much to post for a comment

Answer (score 1):

## Diagnosis

The reasons why your bindings do not work are these:

1. For `RelativeSourceMode.Self` - because `VisualIcon` attached property is not explicitly set on the `ContentControl` and have its default value of `null`.
2. For `RelativeSourceMode.TemplatedParent` - because the `ContentControl` is not part of a template (and if it is, which is not apparent from the code you've provided, probably the value of `VisualIcon` for the templated parent is `null`)
3. For `RelativeSourceMode.FindAncestor` - because `MenuItem` does not set the value of the `MenuItem.Icon` property as its logical child, so until the `ContentControl` is loaded into the visual tree, there's no way to establish the relationship between the two. And, apparently, in this case bindings are resolved prior to that, and for some reason are not re-resolved when the `ContentControl` is finally loaded.

## Solution(s)

There are several approaches you can take to solve this problem, following are some of them.

**I. Set the binding only when the `ContentControl` is loaded**

You could subscribe the following handler to the `ContentControl.Loaded` event:

```
private void ContentControl_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    var control = (ContentControl)sender;
    control.SetBinding(ContentControl.ContentProperty, new Binding
    {
        Path = new PropertyPath(AttachedProperties.VisualIconProperty),
        RelativeSource = new RelativeSource(RelativeSourceMode.FindAncestor)
        {
            AncestorType = typeof(MenuItem),
        },
    });
}
```

Then in your *XAML*:

```
<ContentControl
    Content="{Binding
        Path=(extensions:AttachedProperties.VisualIcon),
        RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=MenuItem}}"
    Loaded="ContentControl_Loaded" (...)>
    (...)
</ContentControl>
```

Note though that if the style is placed in a resource dictionary in a separate file, you'll have to follow [these instructions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/92100/is-it-possible-to-set-code-behind-a-resource-dictionary-in-wpf-for-event-handlin) to get things working.

You could also create custom `MarkupExtension` (e.g. named `DeferredBinding`) to do the job.

**II. Subclass `MenuItem` and set icon as a logical child**

There's not much code to write:

```
public class MyMenuItem : MenuItem
{
    protected override void OnPropertyChanged(DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        base.OnPropertyChanged(e);
        if (e.Property == IconProperty)
        {
            if (e.OldValue != null)
                RemoveLogicalChild(e.OldValue);
            if (e.NewValue != null)
                AddLogicalChild(e.NewValue);
        }
    }
}
```

But the downside is that you always have to remember to use `MyMenuItem` instead of `MenuItem`:

```
<local:MyMenuItem Header="_Open"
      Style="{StaticResource MenuItemStyle}"
      extensions:AttachedProperties.VisualIcon="{DynamicResource appbar.folder.open}" />
```

and:

```
<Style x:Key="MenuItemStyle" TargetType="local:MyMenuItem">
    (...)
</Style>
```

In this case you'd also have bind in `FindAncestor` mode.

**III. Create a helper class that would allow to access the related `MenuItem` from the `ContentControl` through an attached property**

The following helper class contains two dependency properties - `IsEnabled` (I believe it's self explanatory), and `MenuItem`, which is read-only and holds the actual `MenuItem`, on which the target icon is set:

```
public static class MenuItemHelper
{
    /**** Here are the important parts: ****/

    //When IsEnabled changes we need to either hook things up or do the cleanup
    private static void HandleIsEnabledChanged(
        DependencyObject d,
        DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        var item = (MenuItem)d;
        if ((bool)e.NewValue)
            //We set MenuItem attached property for current Icon
            HandleIconChanged(null, item, EventArgs.Empty);
        else
            //We clear the value of MenuItem attached property
            HandleIconChanged(item.Icon, item, EventArgs.Empty);
    }

    //By using an extension method we get hold of the old value without the need
    //to maintain any kind of dictionary, so we don't need to worry about memory leaks
    private static void HandleIconChanged(
        this object oldValue,
        object sender,
        EventArgs e)
    {
        var item = (MenuItem)sender;
        if (oldValue is DependencyObject oldIcon)
            SetMenuItem(oldIcon, null);
        if (item.Icon is DependencyObject newIcon)
            SetMenuItem(newIcon, item);
        //We need to remove the old handler, because it relates to the old icon
        DependencyPropertyDescriptor
            .FromProperty(MenuItem.IconProperty, item.GetType())
            .RemoveValueChanged(item, item.Icon.HandleIconChanged);
        //We add new handler, so that when the icon changes we get correct old icon
        DependencyPropertyDescriptor
            .FromProperty(MenuItem.IconProperty, item.GetType())
            .AddValueChanged(item, item.Icon.HandleIconChanged);
    }

    /**** The rest is just DP boilerplate code ****/

    private static readonly DependencyPropertyKey MenuItemPropertyKey =
        DependencyProperty.RegisterAttachedReadOnly(
            name: "MenuItem",
            propertyType: typeof(MenuItem),
            ownerType: typeof(MenuItemHelper),
            defaultMetadata: new PropertyMetadata(null));

    public static readonly DependencyProperty MenuItemProperty =
        MenuItemPropertyKey.DependencyProperty;

    public static MenuItem GetMenuItem(DependencyObject d)
        => (MenuItem)d.GetValue(MenuItemProperty);

    private static void SetMenuItem(DependencyObject d, MenuItem value)
        => d.SetValue(MenuItemPropertyKey, value);

    public static readonly DependencyProperty IsEnabledProperty =
        DependencyProperty.RegisterAttached(
            name: "IsEnabled",
            propertyType: typeof(bool),
            ownerType: typeof(MenuItemHelper),
            defaultMetadata: new PropertyMetadata(false, HandleIsEnabledChanged));

    public static bool GetIsEnabled(MenuItem item)
        => (bool)item.GetValue(IsEnabledProperty);

    public static void SetIsEnabled(MenuItem item, bool value)
        => item.SetValue(IsEnabledProperty, value);
}
```

Then you only need to set `MenuItemHelper.IsEnabled="True"` on the `MenuItem` and you can use `MenuItemHelper.MenuItem` for the binding (remember that it will be set on the root element of the icon - `Viewbox` in your case):

```
<Style x:Key="MenuItemStyle" TargetType="MenuItem">
    <Setter Property="extensions:MenuItemHelper.IsEnabled" Value="True" />
    <Setter Property="MenuItem.Icon">
        <Setter.Value>
            <Viewbox>
                <ContentControl
                    Content="{Binding
                        Path=(extensions:MenuItemHelper.MenuItem).(extensions:AttachedProperties.VisualIcon),
                        RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=Viewbox}}" (...)>
                    (...)
                </ContentControl>
            </Viewbox>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
```

My personal favorite is #III, because it's most versatile of the three, but perhaps in your particular case other solutions might prove to be more applicable.

Comment: If you're interested in code for `DeferredBinding` let me know.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the detailed explanation! I tried 2 and 3 and both work (had to fix old/new-Icon in MenuItemHelper though; or is that a syntax i don't know about yet?).
Sorry that I didn't mention it before, but it would be great if the solution would also work in the design view. Is there any chance DeferredBinding could do that? Or does there exist another approach, even if it's an ugly one, which would also work in the design view?

Comment: Right, I was about to address that as well - it seems that you have your project code disabled in the designer (hence the `(0)` you've mentioned). Look for an "Enable/Disable project code" toggle button (I believe it's the rightmost one) in the panel at the bottom of the designer, and toggle it on. It might take a restart to take effect.

Comment: As for the code that does not work - I used some C# 7.0 syntax, which by default is only available in Visual Studio 2017, so if you're using an earlier version, it won't compile. See [What's new in C# 7.0](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/dotnet/2016/08/24/whats-new-in-csharp-7-0/), especially [Pattern matching](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/dotnet/2016/08/24/whats-new-in-csharp-7-0/#user-content-pattern-matching).

Comment: Thanks a lot! Found the toggle button, but it's disabled. After some try and error i found out that it get's disabled for projects referencing some c++/cli libs; oh MS.. Maybe that's solved in VS2017 but i cannot use that at work:( Anyway, if there's no other solution to get a working design view (the Style could be totally redefined, i don't care as long as it works, and maybe also removes the need for the manual scale as a bonus) I'll accept your answer. Also, great to read about c# 7.0. Thanks for the link!

Answer (score 0):

The problem with your style approach is, that `Viewbox` will be shared between multiple items when the same style is applied. This can be avoided by creating the `Viewbox` as a separate resource with `x:Shared="False"`. If you want to stick to your current `Canvas-Path` approach, you should turn it into a non-shared resource too, so it becomes re-usable

For demonstration purpose, I set the `MenuItem.Tag` property, but the same should be possible with your attached property idea.

Resources:

```
<!--Notice the added x:Shared-->
<Canvas x:Key="appbar.folder.open" x:Shared="False" Width="76" Height="76" Clip="F1 M 0,0L 76,0L 76,76L 0,76L 0,0">
    <Path Width="44" Height="26" Canvas.Left="19" Canvas.Top="24" Stretch="Fill" Fill="#FF000000" Data="F1 M 19,50L 28,34L 63,34L 54,50L 19,50 Z M 19,28.0001L 35,28C 36,25 37.4999,24.0001 37.4999,24.0001L 48.75,24C 49.3023,24 50,24.6977 50,25.25L 50,28L 53.9999,28.0001L 53.9999,32L 27,32L 19,46.4L 19,28.0001 Z "/>
</Canvas>

<!--Another icon for purpose of demonstration-->
<Canvas x:Key="appbar.folder.close" x:Shared="False" Width="76" Height="76" Clip="F1 M 0,0L 76,0L 76,76L 0,76L 0,0">
    <Path Width="44" Height="26" Canvas.Left="19" Canvas.Top="24" Stretch="Fill" Fill="#FFFF0000" Data="F1 M 19,50L 28,34L 63,34L 54,50L 19,50 Z M 19,28.0001L 35,28C 36,25 37.4999,24.0001 37.4999,24.0001L 48.75,24C 49.3023,24 50,24.6977 50,25.25L 50,28L 53.9999,28.0001L 53.9999,32L 27,32L 19,46.4L 19,28.0001 Z "/>
</Canvas>

<Viewbox x:Key="MenuItemStyle.Icon" x:Shared="False">
    <ContentControl Content="{Binding Path=Tag,RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=MenuItem}}" RenderTransformOrigin="0.5,0.5">
        <ContentControl.RenderTransform>
            <TransformGroup>
                <ScaleTransform ScaleX="2" ScaleY="2"/>
            </TransformGroup>
        </ContentControl.RenderTransform>
    </ContentControl>
</Viewbox>

<Style x:Key="MenuItemStyle" TargetType="MenuItem">
    <Setter Property="Icon" Value="{StaticResource MenuItemStyle.Icon}"/>
</Style>
```

Usage:

```
<Menu x:Name="menu" Height="19" Margin="10,10,10.333,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" ItemContainerStyle="{StaticResource MenuItemStyle}">
    <MenuItem Header="_Open" Tag="{DynamicResource appbar.folder.open}"/>
    <MenuItem Header="_Open 2" Tag="{DynamicResource appbar.folder.open}"/>
    <MenuItem Header="_Close" Tag="{DynamicResource appbar.folder.close}"/>
</Menu>
```

Comment: I tried some combinations (see the updated question) but none did display any icons for me, neither in design view nor during runtime; maybe I did something completely wrong.

Comment: @wonkorealtime Its just a little misunderstanding... each sub-menu has its own `ItemContainerStyle`, so you need to add it to the File menu or use an implicit style resource in order to apply to the sub-items: `<MenuItem Header="_File" ItemContainerStyle="{StaticResource MenuItemStyle4}">`. However, it's not the most designer-friendly version, the icons will only work properly at runtime.